# How to skip scraping with same element with Beautifulsoup4

Tags: html, python-3.x, iframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape videos from a web page, but in that page has two's **iframe** tag..
one for show Facebook page, one the other one is for embed video.
I just want to take the video URL from that..
But when I try to scrape that i got all iframe..

Like this:

```
url_videos = requests.get(link_to_video)

video_link = BeautifulSoup(url_videos.text, 'html.parser')

video_on_iframe = video_link.find('iframe')

print(video_on_iframe)
```

and when I try to run the code above I got this result:

```
<iframe allow="encrypted-media" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="80" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAnimeindoFans%2F&amp;tabs&amp;width=280&amp;height=180&amp;small_header=true&amp;adapt_container_width=true&amp;hide_cover=true&amp;show_facepile=false&amp;appId=123434497681677" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" width="280"></iframe>
<iframe allow="encrypted-media" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="80" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAnimeindoFans%2F&amp;tabs&amp;width=280&amp;height=180&amp;small_header=true&amp;adapt_container_width=true&amp;hide_cover=true&amp;show_facepile=false&amp;appId=123434497681677" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" width="280"></iframe>
<iframe allow="encrypted-media" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="80" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAnimeindoFans%2F&amp;tabs&amp;width=280&amp;height=180&amp;small_header=true&amp;adapt_container_width=true&amp;hide_cover=true&amp;show_facepile=false&amp;appId=123434497681677" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" width="280"></iframe>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="380" scrolling="no" src="http://www.mp4upload.com/embed-q7xxgge1yu1c.html" type="text/html" width="640">
</iframe>
<iframe allow="encrypted-media" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="80" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAnimeindoFans%2F&amp;tabs&amp;width=280&amp;height=180&amp;small_header=true&amp;adapt_container_width=true&amp;hide_cover=true&amp;show_facepile=false&amp;appId=123434497681677" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" width="280"></iframe>
<iframe allow="encrypted-media" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="80" scrolling="no" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FAnimeindoFans%2F&amp;tabs&amp;width=280&amp;height=180&amp;small_header=true&amp;adapt_container_width=true&amp;hide_cover=true&amp;show_facepile=false&amp;appId=123434497681677" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" width="280"></iframe>
```

I don't need that Facebook **iframe**, I just need the video URL from other **iframe** with attribute `height="380"` and `width="280"`

When I try to specify more details in **find()** method like this:

```
video_on_iframe = video_link.find('iframe', width=640, height=380)
```

I got this:

```
None
None
None
<iframe frameborder="0" height="380" scrolling="no" src="http://www.mp4upload.com/embed-q7xxgge1yu1c.html" type="text/html" width="640">
</iframe>
None
None
```

An **iframe** elements and None in the others..

So.. my question is how to just find all `iframe', width=640, height=380` value and skip the `None` result in the others..?

Answer (score 0):

You could also require `src` attribute to be present:

```
video_on_iframe = video_link.find('iframe', src=True)
```

Or, combined with checks for `width` and `height`:

```
video_on_iframe = video_link.find('iframe', src=True, width=640, height=380)
```

Comment: Hy.. @alecxe, Thanks for your reply to my question, this is the second time you're answer my question..
But in this one, I still got same result as a like my code in the above, and not effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_all` to find all videos with that dimensions and with the src attribute.

```
video_on_iframe = [video["src"] for video in video_link.find_all('iframe', width=640, 
height=380, src=True)]
print(video_on_iframe)
```

> [u'http://www.mp4upload.com/embed-q7xxgge1yu1c.html']
>   [Finished in 0.2s]

Comment: Instead of _None_, I got empty list with that code @Zroq

Comment: Now I'm use this code:




`video_on_iframe = video_link.find('iframe', allow='encrypted-media' == False)
if video_on_iframe is not None:
   URL_VIDEOS = video_on_iframe['src']`




But the process is very slow..

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> video_on_frame = video_link.find_all('iframe', height = '380')## This means I wanna scrape iframe who has height value 380 . You can also use widht. 
> link_array = []
> for link in video_on_frame:  ## Your html has 1 iframe in video_on_frame format.
>
>         get_iframe_url = link['src'] ## find iframe's src 
>            
>
>
>         try:
>             link_array.append(get_iframe_url) ## add src into a array
>
>         except:
>              link_array.append('Error')
> ```

print(link_array) will show your url what you want

Comment: Hey @Omer, Thank you for your attention reply my question, but It still don't work Omer, instead of _None_ I got empty _list_.

Comment: Now I'm use this code: `video_on_iframe = video_link.find('iframe', allow='encrypted-media' == False) if video_on_iframe is not None: URL_VIDEOS = video_on_iframe['src']`  But the process is very slow..